# Connecting Roland vb-99 to Personal Computer (USB)

Tags: bass-guitar

I have a Roland vb-99 and I'm trying to use its default editor (vb-editor).
When I open the program it asks me to perform the midi setup but when I open it I can't find the vb-99 in midi in or out.
I've been fiddling for ages with the system menu ---> midi in the vb-99 software without luck.

Drivers are installed correctly.

Anybody has hints? :(

Comment: This doesn't feel like the right place to ask the question. It seems like it's standard functionality of the device, which you should be able to get support for free from Roland.

Comment: @slim I thought this at first too, but based on [this meta question](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/296/are-technical-questions-about-how-to-use-a-particular-product-on-topic), I think it's on-topic actually. Just my 2¢ =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should uninstall and re-install the driver to be safe, for starters.

According to the [owner's manual](http://media.rolandus.com/manuals/VB-99_OM.pdf) on the [Roland website](http://www.rolandus.com/support/owners_manuals) (Chapter 6, page 66):

> You cannot use MIDI when `STNDRD` is selected as the driver mode.
>
> If you want to use MIDI with the USB connection, set the VB-99 to the
>   advanced driver mode.